# how to change joomla required field red color

Tags: css, input, joomla, colors, required

I want to change red color of required input field in joomla that is showed if it is empty. Where the code to control this.

Comment: which input fields are you talking about? backend or frontend? and which version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: actually I am talking frontend input field. I want to find the code of it to know how I control validate.js I am editing that file for my requriement but I couldn understand how to kontrol specific part of form and attributes etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Joomla backend input fields, for example when you got o add a new menu item, The "menu title" is required, then you will need to go to:

```
administrator/templates/bluestork/css/template.css   >>   line 133
```

```css
input.required {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Can only assume this is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the css for `input.required` on `background-color` (or whatever) in your own css with `!important` ([What does important mean in CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)).

For example... `media/your_component/css/mystyle.css`

```css
input.required {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```